# Spouses in Tanach whose names start with the same letter?

Tags: tanach, names, aleph-bet-letters

This is one of those parsha sheet trivia questions:  There are **six** couples in Tanach where the names of the spouses start with the same letter.  Who are they?

I've got five of them, but I can't think of the sixth.  Any help?

1. אחאב & איזבל
2. אחשורוש & אסתר
3. עשו & עדה (Genesis 36:10)
4. אהרון & אלישבע (Exodus 6:23)
5. נח & נעמה (According to Midrash, quoted by Rashi on Genesis 4:22)

Comment: Despite being a riddle question, I honestly don't know the answer.

Comment: Gotta be _Sh'lomo_....

Comment: @shmuel nope not a riddle.

Comment: There are probably more than six.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic as a riddle

Comment: בן ישי and בת שבע.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139/riddle-questions-on-se It seems like the main problem with riddle questions is that they conceal information, but this question doesn't.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

עתניאל בן קנז ועכסה בת כלב
— see 
[Judges 1:13](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%92)

EDIT:
I found some more:

יואש מלך יהודה ויהועדן - See [Kings II 14:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%91)

אחז מלך יהודה ואבי בת-זכריה - See [Kings II 18:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%97_%D7%91)

חזקיהו מלך יהודה וחפצי-בה - See [Kings II 21:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%90_%D7%90)

מנשה מלך יהודה ומשלמת בת חרוץ - See [Kings II 21:19](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%98)

Comment: +1. That probably was indeed the sixth one that the author of the parsha sheet meant - it's a lot more well-known than any of mine.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't even thought of checking among the mothers of the kings of Yehudah.

Comment: @Alex I'm still not satisfied because Noach and Naamah is a midrash. I expect the question wanted ones based in the psukim that people would know. There has to be another one...

Answer (score 22):

There are the following others:

אביהיל and אבישור (I Chron. 2:29)

מעכה and מכיר (ibid. 7:16)

שלחו אותם and שחרים (ibid. 8:8, according to Radak, Metzudos and Malbim)

יהושבעת and יהוידע (II Chron. 22:11)

Comment: How did you do that???

Comment: @Hod: searched Tanach for אשת. (Which means that there might be others I've missed, too: that wouldn't have found Aharon and Elisheva, for example.)