# Deviations of Ralbag from normative Jewish theology

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rishonim, ralbag

In an [article](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/704638/) about the Rashba's views on science, [Rabbi Dr. David Horwitz](https://www.yu.edu/riets/faculty/roshei-yeshiva/rabbi-david-horwitz) throws in the following sentence (p. 53):

> **No less than a radical thinker** than R. Levi ben Gershom (Ralbag), **who had no qualms about deviating from the normative Jewish theological position on a number of issues**, was a firm believer in the effects of stars upon human life, and based his opinion on empirical evidence.

What issues deviating from the normative Jewish theological position could he be alluding to? I don't believe the effect of stars is one of them as the author is showing how Ralbag conformed with the view of other Rishonim who argued on the [view of the Rambam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53765/1739).

Comment: He believed God did not know the future, Moshe was not qualitatively different than any other human being, (just was smarter and more "refined" but possible someone greater than Moshe could arise), greatly minimized certain miracles and placed them more in the terms of nature, God doesn't recognize individual humans, among other things.  (source: I took a class with Rabbi Horwitz)

Comment: R Horwitz studied Ralbag for his doctorate btw

Comment: If someone wants to summarize those sources (with citations to his commentary) I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Ralbag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gersonides) held of a number of views which might be considered problematic, or against normative theology. The first three listed below, are more deviant than the subsequent two. The former would be considered a theological anomaly (and perhaps even heretical) even in Ralbag's own milieu. The latter would probably not have caused a stir for many of the [*rishonim*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishonim), but in more recent times they might be considered outside of the standard Jewish [*hashkafa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashkafa). The final three are probably in their own categories, and are a bit harder to pin down.

Note that while while each of the "deviant" views below might have other *rishonim* who subscribe to it as well, the factor that makes Ralbag the "radical thinker" is that he held of **all of these** "deviant" views.

### **1) Omniscience**

Ralbag believed that God only knows what a person will do based on his natural makeup and celestial influence. However the person's free will can overpower these, and he can end up choosing something that God did not know he would choose. The entire Book 3 of Ralbag's *[Milchamot Hashem (Wars of the Lord)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milhamoth_ha-Shem#Milhamoth_ha-Shem_of_Levi_ben_Gershom,_14th_century)* is devoted to the topic of God's knowledge, and he discusses it a bunch of times in his commentary to the Torah as well. For example, in his discussion of [the destruction of Sodom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodom_and_Gomorrah#The_Judgment_upon_Sodom_and_Gomorrah) he writes that it would have been possible for the inhabitants of Sodom to have acted in a way contrary to how God "knew" they would act:

> ולזה יתכן שיהיה מה שיעשוהו האנשים זולת מה שידע ה' יתע' מסדור פעולותיהם
>   וזה כי הוא ידע פעולותיהם מהצד אשר אפשר בהם הידיעה והוא הצד אשר בו הם
>   מסודרות ומוגבלותו ואולם אשר בו הם אפשריות לא תתכן בהם הידיעה שאם הנחנו
>   שתתכן בהם הידיעה לא יתקיים שתהיינה אפשריות

### **2) Omnipotence**

Ralbag limited God's ability to perform miracles. According to him, a possible miracle is one where God spontaneously generates something that can exist in nature but cannot be spontaneously generated in nature. However God cannot generate something that cannot exist in nature in the first place. This is also discussed in a bunch of places. One example is his discussion by [the Splitting of the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Red_Sea) where he gives the example that God was able to turn Moses's staff into a snake because snakes can exist in nature:

> וזה שכבר השרשנו שם שהמופתים יהיו בדברים אשר לא ימנע היותם בעצמם מצד
>   הטבע ואם היה שיהיה נמנע מצד הטבע שיהיו מאלו הסבות שיתחדשו מהם כאלו
>   תאמר כי אע"פ שחדוש הנחש מהמטה הוא נמנע מצד הטבע הנה מציאות הנחש בעצמו
>   איננו נמנע מצד הטבע

### **3) Creation**

Ralbag did not believe in the standard doctrine of *creatio [ex nihilo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_nihilo)*. Much of Book 6 of *Wars of the Lord* is devoted to this topic. He begins Part 2, Chapter 1, for instance, with:

> It is quite clear that religious principles do not imply the belief in
>   creation *ex nihilo*. (Seymour Feldman translation)

I discussed his view of creation at greater length in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97334/13438).

### **4) Critical of the Sages**

Ralbag often criticizes the views of the [Sages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chazal). Here are a few examples:

**A.** The Sages state ([Sanhedrin 59b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=59b&format=pdf)) that God originally did not allow man to eat meat, and only permitted it later to the children of [Noah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah). Ralbag [objects to this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96321/13438) on the philosophical grounds that God's will is unchangeable, and he refers to the idea as שקר עצום ראוי שיברח ממנו כל בעל דת/דעת – a complete falsehood from which anyone with knowledge (alternatively, with religion) should flee.

**B.** The Sages state ([Bava Basra 120a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=120&format=pdf)) that [Yocheved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jochebed) was born "between the walls" and was thus 130 years old when she gave birth to [Moshe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses). Ralbag rejects this since the Torah does not publicize this, which, had it happened, would have been a greater miracle than [Sarah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarah) giving birth to [Yitzchak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac) at the age of 90. He asserts that the Sages made this up in order to instill in the masses the belief in the ability of God to perform miracles.

> וראוי שתדע כי מה שאמרו ז"ל שנולדה בין החומות אמרו זה על דרך הדרש
>   להועיל להמון וליסד בלבם עוצם יכולת השם יתעלה לעשות הפלאים

**C.** He criticizes the geometry of the Sages who state ([Yoma 72b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=72b&format=pdf)) that the walls of the [Ark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark_of_the_Covenant) were a *[tefach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_and_Talmudic_units_of_measurement#Length_and_distance)* thick, noting that all the gold donated to the [Mishkan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabernacle) would not have been enough to make such thick walls.

> ולא יתכן שיהיה עובי ארנות הזהב טפח כמו שאמרו ז"ל כי לא יתכן שישלם אחד מאלו הארונות בזה העובי מכל הזהב הנזכר באלה פקודי העשוי למלאכה וזה יתבאר למי שעיין בהנדסה עיון מעט ואולם אמרו זה ז"ל להורות על שכבר היה לאלו הארונות עובי מורגש

### **5) Divine Providence**

Ralbag believed that only some people are subject to individual Divine Providence. For example in *Wars of the Lord* Book 4 Chapter 4 he writes:

> Since it has been shown that it is false to say that there is no
>   individual providence at all and that it is also false to say that
>   there is individual providence operating in each and every person, it
>   is evident that individual providence must operate in some people but
>   not in others. (Seymour Feldman translation)

### **6) Interpreting the Torah**

While other *rishonim* had no problem ignoring or rejecting the Sages' interpretations of the Torah in favor of more *[peshat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peshat)*-based interpretations, Ralbag went a step further and apparently rejected the entire edifice of Rabbinic Derivations even for actual *[halachos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halakha)*/*[mitzvos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitzvah)*. He apparently thought that all *derashos* and derivations using [the 13 Principles of Exposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraita_of_Rabbi_Ishmael) were really *[asmachtos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asmachta_(Talmudical_hermeneutics))*, with the actual law being known via tradition. In his introduction to his commentary he writes:

> והנה בביאורינו במצות ושרשים אשר מהם יצאו כל דיניהם אשר התבארו בחכמה
>   התלמודית לא יהיה מנהגנו בכל המקומות לסמוך אותם השרשים אל המקומות אשר
>   סמכו אותם חכמי התלמוד באחת מי"ג מדות לפי מנהגם וזה שהם סמכו אלו הדברים
>   האמתיים המקובלים להם במצות התורה לפסוקים ההם להיותם כדמות רמז ואסמכתא
>   לדברים ההם לא שיהיה דעתם שיהיה מוצא אלו הדינין מאלו המקומות כי כבר
>   יוכל האדם להפך כל דיני התורה בכמו אלו ההקשים עד שאפשר בהם לטהר את השרץ
>   כמו שזכרו ז"ל אבל נסמוך אותם אל פשטי הפסוקים אשר אפשר שיצאו הדינין
>   האלו מהם כי בזה תתיישב הנפש יותר ואין בזה יציאה מדברי רז"ל כי הם לא
>   כוונו כמו שאמרנו שיהיה עכ"פ מוצא הדינים ההם מהמקומות אשר סמכו אותם להם
>   אבל הם אצלם מקובלים איש מפי איש עד משה רבינו ובקשו להם רמז מן הכתוב
>   כמו שזכר הרב המורה בספר המצות ובפירוש המשנה

Note that he does not say that he will disagree with the conclusions of the Sages. He simply objects to their methodology of deriving laws because the same methodology can be used to derive the exact opposite. Instead he formulates a list of nine premises that he will use in interpreting *mitzvos*.

One example of the discrepancy between Ralbag's interpretation and that of the Sages is by the *mitzvah* of [*tefillin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefillin). The Torah says to tie a sign on your hand and put *totafos* between your eyes. The Sages ([Menachos 36b-37b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=36b&format=pdf)) interpreted various verses to explain that the *tefillin shel yad* should be on your left hand and that the *tefillin shel rosh* should be on the upper part of the head. Ralbag, on the other hand, simply states that *tefillin shel yad* must be on the left hand since one of his premises is that all significant actions (in this case binding the *tefillin*) are done with the right hand.

> וראוי שתדע כי התפילין של יד יחוייב שיהיו ביד שמאל וזה כי כבר אמר בהם
>   וקשרתם לאות על ידיך בפרשיות שמע ישראל והיה אם שמע ופעל הקשירה הזאת
>   יחויב שיעשה ביד הימנית כמו שהתבאר בשרשים הכוללים ולזה יחוייב שיהיו
>   התפילין של יד ביד השמאלית כי לא יתכן שנקשר אותם ביד הימנית אם יהיו
>   התפילין ביד הימנית וזה מבואר בנפשו

Regarding the placement of the *tefillin shel rosh* [he simply says](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92684/why-are-tefillin-worn-on-the-head-and-not-between-the-eyes/92687#92687) that it can't be literally between the eyes because there is no room there, it would block your vision, and would cause the nations to mock us, which are things that the Torah would never command us.

> וכן אין הכוונה שנניח התפילין של ראש בין העינים מפני מה שאמרה התורה
>   ולזכרון בין עינך ולטוטפות בין עינך וזה כי אין שם מקום יתכן שיונחו בו
>   עם שהם יהיו סנורים בעינינו ר"ל שכבר ימנעוהו מראית הדברים כהוגן עם שזה
>   יהיה דבר יביא אותנו להיות ללעג ולשחוק לשאר העמים והנה התורה לא תצוה
>   לעשות כמו אלו הדברים

### **7) Theophany at Sinai**

Ralbag also did not subscribe to the standard view of the Revelation at Sinai. According to [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) the Revelation at Sinai is the only way we know that Moshe is true and his Torah is true. As he writes in [Hilchos Yesodei HaTorah 8:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=76):

> משה רבינו לא האמינו בו ישראל מפני האותות שעשה שהמאמין על פי האותות יש
>   בלבו דופי שאפשר שיעשה האות בלט וכשוף אלא כל האותות שעשה משה במדבר לפי
>   הצורך עשאם לא להביא ראיה על הנבואה היה צריך להשקיע את המצריים קרע את
>   הים והצלילן בתוכו צרכנו למזון הוריד לנו את המן צמאו בקע להן את האבן
>   כפרו בו עדת קרח בלעה אותן הארץ וכן שאר כל האותות ובמה האמינו בו במעמד
>   הר סיני שעינינו ראו ולא זר ואזנינו שמעו ולא אחר האש והקולות והלפידים
>   והוא נגש אל הערפל והקול מדבר אליו ואנו שומעים משה משה לך אמור להן כך
>   וכך וכן הוא אומר פנים בפנים דבר ה' עמכם ונאמר לא את אבותינו כרת ה' את
>   הברית הזאת ומנין שמעמד הר סיני לבדו היא הראיה לנבואתו שהיא אמת שאין בו
>   דופי שנאמר הנה אנכי בא אליך בעב הענן בעבור ישמע העם בדברי עמך וגם בך
>   יאמינו לעולם מכלל שקודם דבר זה לא האמינו בו נאמנות שהיא עומדת לעולם
>   אלא נאמנות שיש אחריה הרהור ומחשבה
>
> The Jews did not believe in Moses, our teacher, because of the wonders
>   that he performed. Whenever anyone's belief is based on wonders, [the
>   commitment of] his heart has shortcomings, because it is possible to
>   perform a wonder through magic or sorcery.
>
> All the wonders performed by Moses in the desert were not intended to
>   serve as proof [of the legitimacy] of his prophecy, but rather were
>   performed for a purpose. It was necessary to drown the Egyptians, so
>   he split the sea and sank them in it. We needed food, so he provided
>   us with manna. We were thirsty, so he split the rock [providing us
>   with water]. Korach's band mutinied against him, so the earth
>   swallowed them up. The same applies to the other wonders.
>
> What is the source of our belief in him? The [revelation] at Mount
>   Sinai. Our eyes saw, and not a stranger's. Our ears heard, and not
>   another's. There was fire, thunder, and lightning. He entered the
>   thick clouds; the Voice spoke to him and we heard, "Moses, Moses, go
>   tell them the following:...."
>
> Thus, [Deuteronomy 5:4] relates: "Face to face, God spoke to you," and
>   [Deuteronomy 5:3] states: "God did not make this covenant with our
>   fathers, [but with us, who are all here alive today]."
>
> How is it known that the [revelation] at Mount Sinai alone is proof of
>   the truth of Moses' prophecy that leaves no shortcoming? [Exodus 19:9]
>   states: "Behold, I will come to you in a thick cloud, so that the
>   people will hear Me speaking to you, [so that] they will believe in
>   you forever." It appears that before this happened, they did not
>   believe in him with a faith that would last forever, but rather with a
>   faith that allowed for suspicions and doubts. ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904992/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Eight.htm))

Standard interpretations assume that all the people experienced some prophetic revelation, and that is what makes the event at Sinai unique. Ralbag, however, asserts that the people did not actually experience a prophetic revelation. Rather, God spoke to Moshe and Moshe relayed the commandments to the people, and this was accompanied by some miraculous phenomenon that verified that God was speaking to Moshe and specifically telling him what he was repeating over.

> והנה מה שאמרו ישראל כל אשר  דבר יי נעשה היה אפשר שיובן על שני פנים
>   האחד שיהיו להם אות כי השם יתע' מדבר עמו אלו הדברים אשר יצוה אותם עליהם
>   ויהיה הרצון באמרו כל אשר דבר יי נעשה כל אשר דבר יי לך נעשה אבל רצוננו
>   שיתברר לנו שדבר ה' לך והשני הוא שיהיה הדבור דבור השם יתע' לא דבור משה
>   וזה כי אע"פ שיתברר להם שהשם מדבר עמו הנה לא יתברר להם שיהיה הדבור אשר
>   ידבר להם משה הוא הדבור אשר דבר אליו השם יתעלה והנה לא היו ישראל סכלים
>   שירצו שידבר להם השם יתעלה בעצמו כי זה בלתי אפשר להם אבל רצו
>   שיתחדש [להם] על דרך מופת מהשם יתע' מה שיודיע להם רצון השם יתעלה
>   מזולת שישמעו זה מפי משה כמו שהכירו ענין מצות שבת מפני המן קודם שישמעו
>   זה מפי משה והנה השיב משה דברי העם אל ה' והבין אותם משה אז לפי האופן
>   הראשון רוצה לומר שהם רצו שיהיה להם אות יעיד להם כי השם יתע' מדבר עמו
>   ואז יעשו כל אשר דבר ה' לו ובאתהו התשובה מהשם יתע' לפי מה שהבין אותו
>   משה מדבריהם לסבה שזכרנו במה שקדם ואמר אליו הנה אנכי בא אליך בעב הענן
>   בעבור יראה העם בדברי עמך וגם בך יאמינו לעולם במה שתדבר להם בשמי אחר
>   שכבר יתפרסם להם שאנכי מדבר עמך והנה פירשנו אמרו בעבור ישמע בעבור
>   יראה לפי שהחושים יבואו לפעמים קצתם תחת קצת אמר ראה ריח בני וכל העם
>   ראים את הקלות וראה את ערותה וכן אמר ומתוק האור וטוב לעינים כאלו היה
>   הראות חוש הטעם או יהיה ישמע מענין הקבלה כטעם והיה אם שמוע תשמע בקול יי
>   ולא שמעו בקולי ויהיה הרצון בזה הנה אנכי בא אליך בעב הענן לעיניהם וזה
>   יהיה להם לאות שאני מדבר עמך והנה אעשה להם זה האות בעבור ישמע העם במה
>   שאדבר עמך ויקיימו הדברים ההם וגם בך יאמינו לעולם בכל מה שתדבר להם בשמי
>   מפני מה שיתפרסם להם שאני מדבר עמך והנה זה הפירוש השני יותר נכון לפי מה
>   שאחשוב וכאשר שמע זה המאמר מהשם יתעלה שב להתבונן במה שאמרו ישראל וידע
>   שהם כוונו בזה שיהיה המדבר להם השם יתעלה לא משה והנה הגיד משה דברי העם
>   אל ה' לפי זאת הכוונה השנית ולזה אמר לו השם יתע' כי מפני שהם רוצים
>   שיגיע להם קול דברים מהשם יתע' כבר יחוייב שתקדשם שלא יגשו אל אשה ויכבסו
>   שמלותם לכבוד השם יתע' כדי שיהיו נקיים מטומאות ובזה האופן יהיו נכונים
>   ליום השלישי לשמוע קול הדברים שיגיע מהשם יתע' על דרך המופת

In other words, it appears that according to Ralbag the Revelation on Sinai was simply a miracle like any other miracle Moshe performed. According to this, the entire proof of the truth of Moshe and his Torah is called into question.<sup>1</sup>

### 8) Prophetic Inaccuracy

Ralbag believed that it was possible for prophets to have an incorrect understanding of the world, and that their prophecies could reflect these misunderstandings. For instance, in his commentary to Genesis 15:4 he explains that God gave Abraham a vision of numerous stars even though in reality there are very few stars, because Abraham (incorrectly) believed that there were numerous stars. Similarly God gave Ezekiel a vision in which the celestial bodies made sounds, since that is what Ezekiel (incorrectly) believed was the reality.

> והנה מספר הכוכבים לא היה נודע בימי אברם ולזה הראהו המדמה בעת הנבואה ענין ריבוי הכוכבים למשל הריבוי המופלג אשר ייעד אותו ה' יתעלה שיהיה בזרעו וכזה תמצא שראה יחזקאל בעת הנבואה שיהיה לגלגלים קולות מצד מה שהיה מאמין מזה הענין כמו שזכר הרב המורה כי לא יחוייב שיהיו לנביא כל הדעות האמיתיות בענין סודות המציאות

---

<sup>1.Interestingly, Rambam himself in *Guide for the Perplexed* seems to explain the Revelation at Sinai in some similar way to Ralbag. In [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97463/what-is-the-qualitative-difference-between-the-revelation-at-sinai-and-other-mir) I noted the difficulty of reconciling this with Rambam's statement quoted here that the Revelation on Sinai was fundamentally different from other miracles.</sup>

Comment: Wow! This is one of the most thorough answers I have seen on this site (in my whole week here lol).  A big +1.  But at a certain point "kol hamosif gorea", and I agree with mevaqesh that some of this is unnecessary to make your points, and when contrasted with others isn't that radical.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I've been here for over two years, and I can tell you this is a very thorough post.

Comment: Note that that approach to derashot was that of the geonim. And a millennium later, of the Dorot HaRishonim.

Comment: Another facet of omnipotence - Ralbag seems to feel that G-d couldn't prevent the destruction of all of humanity. He writes that the mistake of the Tower of Bavel wanting to gather all in one place was that they subject themselves to the risk of total annihilation by one large disaster, which would be prevented if they spread out. Apparently, Ralbag felt G-d couldn't prevent the disaster and therefore had to scatter them around for safe-keeping.

Comment: @Yez That might be more related to his view on Divine Providence and letting nature run its course than his view on omnipotence.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin He holds mostly like the Rambam (obviously a one line excerpt can't portray a view that took him the entire book 4 of *Milchamot Hashem* to spell out). Even so, a good 100 years had passed since Rambam, and others did not agree with Rambam. I did note in the post, though, that not all the examples are equally controversial.

Comment: end: https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_HaRivash.45?vhe=Rivash_Responsa,_Vilna,_1879&lang=he

Comment: @Alex do you happen to know if there is an English translation of Ralbag's commentary on the Torah?

Comment: I don’t believe so (unless you’re counting individual passages such as in various posts on this site). But there are translations of his Milchamos Hashem, which has some overlap (especially Book VI to Bereishis). @רבותמחשבות

Comment: How do we know these ideas of Ralbag are deviated from his contemporaries? #5 about hashgacha for instance is the same opinion held by Ramban Vayeira 18:19 and Rabeinu Bachya Vayishlach beginning of ch 34.

Answer (score 9):

The Rivash in his Tshuvos #45  mentioned that some of the Ralbag's beliefs that he felt were influenced by nontraditional wisdom. Rivash does mention that Ralbag wrote otherwise nice works.

Rivash pointed to a few problematic ones in particular. One, in regard to Hashem's knowledge of the future. Two,   concerning the sun standing still for Yehoshua 'he wrote things which are assur to hear'. He also points to the beliefs surrounding understanding the soul and Hashem's involvement in punishing evildoers in this world.

Rivash says all these problematic ideas are written in his seffer Milchamos Hashem.

A further Tshuva in Rivash, #118, also discuses the Ralbag's opinion about Hashem's knowledge of the future. Rivash there explains the difference between Ralbag's philosophy and the [Ravad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_David)'s whom the one posing the question thought were similar.

Comment: Don't read https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23017/759

Comment: Exactly:) What's interesting is that Ralbag was also using Rambam's philosophy that Hashem cannot do the impossible, and Rivash seems to imply that these ideas from Ralbag are not in line with Rambam either.

Comment: Clarified that the intent is Raavad of Posquières; not [R. Avraham ibn Daud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Daud) (whose views actually **are** similar to Ralbag's).

Comment: Could you please add detail as to what these beliefs entail or a location where I can see them myself? (Preferably both)